# Apache/PHP behind Nginx Reverse Proxy slower than expected

Tags: php, apache, proxy, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm not certain what I'm missing, or overlooking.  Or maybe I'm just not thinking about something correctly.

I am testing Apache/PHP behind an Nginx reverse proxy, (Nginx is performing GZIP, KeepAlive, and SSL).

Testing using Apache Bench from another server within the same local network can perform 500 connections (100 concurrent) in 0.349 seconds.  However, when I connect using a browser, the timeline for the page load shows 2 seconds of waiting for a server response.

The only thing I can think is that the proxy for the network is playing a role (the server is outside the proxy, so requests from my browser pass through the proxy).  I'm getting 'Vary-Accept' header responses for encoding, which makes me think that might be the issue.  When I use WBOX from my computer, however, it returns 2-30ms response times.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I resolved the issue and hopefully this will help others.  I had caching disabled correctly on Nginx, and was passing through a no-cache header, however I had SendFile enabled on Nginx, and which appears to have been causing it to still cache files regardless of my settings.  I disabled this feature, and cleared the cache on the browser, and it's been making fast requests ever since.

I'm not certain if SendFile writes to disk in the same way that cache might, and that was causing the issue, but disabling certainly solved a ton of issues.